# Change background of all columns with the Converter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I wrote a converter and I'm able to set a cell color depending on the value in the row. This is my column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBrushConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

It works great, but I have to add this piece of code for every column. Is there a way to declare this `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle` for all columns?

Thanks

Comment: If you just put that style in the datagrid resources then I would think it'd apply to all textblocks in the datagrid. Maybe including headers.. but you could maybe make the converter cope with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another implicit `Style` that targets `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<Resources>    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
        <Setter Property="ElementStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBrushConverter}}" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Seter>
    </Style>
</Resources>
```